# How do I get indices of manually created vertex group via python?

Tags: python, blender-internal-render-engine

I manually created a vertex group with needed vertices in blender. How do I get indices of its vertices to then create a vertex group with this vertices via python?

Comment: How do you access the vertex group? Could you post your code please?

Comment: I manually created my vertex group in blender, w/o python, and I want to know how can I do the same, but via python

Comment: Based on the selection in *Edit Mode* or on what criteria?

Comment: Same question here https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/145972/how-to-select-and-assign-vertices-to-a-vertex-group-via-python What make indicated answer not enough for you?