How do I delete all bones from a scene that DONT have any weight information for meshes in the scene using python
I have a .blend file that contains a armature and clothing from a character. But the Base Character mesh has been removed from the blend file.
all parts of this armature may have weights referencing other deleted meshes. but some of them only have weights for the clothing, IE the feet bones are not going to have valuable weights for a t-shirt.
How do I programmatic go through using python and delete any of these bones that are not useful for the remaining meshes in the scene.
import bpy

def remove_unused_bones(blend_file):

    # Load the Blender file
    bpy.ops.wm.open_mainfile(filepath=blend_file)

    for armature in bpy.data.armatures:
        bones = armature.edit_bones
        
        # Iterate over each bone
        for bone in bones:
            # Check if the bone has any weights on any mesh
            for mesh in bpy.data.meshes:
                # I cant seem to figure out how to link the vertex data to the mesh.

            # If the bone has no weights, remove it
            if not has_weights:
                bpy.ops.armature.delete_bone()

        # Save the modified Blender file
        bpy.ops.wm.save_mainfile(filepath=blend_file)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    if len(sys.argv) < 2:
        print("Usage: python remove_unused_bones.py <blender_file>")
        sys.exit(1)
    remove_unused_bones(sys.argv[1])


The object knows the vertex groups. Have a look here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/145972/107598. So, you need to iterate over the bpy.data.objects, not over the meshes. Also, you should create a (copy) list of the bones names first, because you cannot iterate over a list and remove entries from it at the same time. It will result in an error or even worse unpredictable behavior or a crash.

Was this code generated by some AI chat assistant or other LLM powerwed tool? If so please provide attribution to the used tool or site.

Thanks @blunder For pointing me in the right direction.
Here is a working function that does what I wanted.
def objHasAnyWeights(obj,vgroup):
    group_index = vgroup.index
    for i, v in enumerate(obj.data.vertices):
        for g in v.groups:
            if g.group == group_index:
                if g.weight > 0:
                    return 1  # Return 1 immediately upon finding a positive weight
                break  # No need to check further weights in the same vertex
    return 0  # No positive weights found

def walkTreeGetDelete(thisbone,weightless_bones,result):
    if not thisbone: #cant have weight if you dont exist.
        return False
    haschildwightedbone = False
    for bone in thisbone.children: #recurse
        if walkTreeGetDelete(bone,weightless_bones,result):
            haschildwightedbone = True
    if haschildwightedbone: #if any of the children have weight just return true
        return True
    if thisbone.name in weightless_bones: #non of my children have weight, do i have weight?
        result.append(thisbone.name)
        return False
    return True #I have weight

def remove_unused_bones(blend_file):

    # Load the Blender file
    bpy.ops.wm.open_mainfile(filepath=blend_file)
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')

    # Create a set to store bones that have weights on meshes in the scene
    weightless_bones = []
    result=[]

    # Iterate over each armature
    for armature in bpy.data.armatures:

        # Iterate over each object
        for obj in bpy.data.objects:
            group_vertexcount = {}

            #Iterate over each group on object, these should be the name of the bone.
            for group in obj.vertex_groups:
                #Vertexes hold the data? Semms a bit backwords but ok.
                for vertex in obj.data.vertices:
                    #each vertex has a vertex group.
                    for vg in vertex.groups:
                        if group.name not in group_vertexcount:
                                group_vertexcount[group.name] = {}
                                group_vertexcount[group.name]['vertices'] = 0
                                group_vertexcount[group.name]['weights'] = 0
                        if(group_vertexcount[group.name]['vertices'] == 0):
                            group_vertexcount[group.name]['vertices'] = len(obj.data.vertices)
                        #This is terribly slow, but it works. doubt I can thread it
                        if group_vertexcount[group.name]['weights'] == 0: #If i havent found a weight yet, check each vertex
                            group_vertexcount[group.name]['weights'] = objHasAnyWeights(obj, group)
                if group.name not in weightless_bones and group_vertexcount[group.name]['weights'] == 0:
                    weightless_bones.append(group.name)
                print(f"{obj.name} -> {group.name} : {group_vertexcount[group.name]['vertices']} vertices {group_vertexcount[group.name]['weights']} weight")

        walkTreeGetDelete(armature.edit_bones[0],weightless_bones,result)

        for bone in result:
            armature.edit_bones.remove(armature.edit_bones[bone])

        # Save the modified Blender file
        bpy.ops.wm.save_mainfile(filepath=blend_file)


I think its a bit backwards that i have to iterate over each vertex to get its group, but its the only way i found it works. Its terribly slow since i have to loop over every vertex then loop again.
Wish there was an easyer way.
